# rule of thumb for generalizing observations to population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, statistical-power, reporting, marketing

I recently had a question from a co-worker, “How big a sample would you need to feel comfortable communicating figures?”

My answer was two part:

1) if we’re trying to show something made a difference like “this product placement increased sales by 10%.”  Then we’re talking power:

```
power ~ sqrt(sample size)*(difference)/(standard deviation)
```

so the question comes down to how sure you want to be you detected a difference and how big a difference you want to be able to detect.

2) For general observations about the population like “23% of men buy shoes.”  Then a rule of thumb like:

```
0.23 +/- 1/sqrt(sample size)
```

A very simplified version of a confidence interval.

We’re not talking about cancer cures, it’s retail sales.  I’m wondering if my answers seem reasonable, or if I’m over simplifying things.  We have millions of transactions a day, and we’re looking at samples in the thousands.